# ajax event="rowSelect" does not work when I use viewAction and viewParam

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have the next situation. I tried to recreate the error from my project in a clean project.

I have a simple index page with 2 links

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="true">
        </p:messages>
        <div class="ui-fluid" jsf:id="itemForm">

            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{workRequestController.confirmWorkRequest}" update=":mainForm:itemForm">Send Parameter </p:commandLink>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:link href="main.xhtml">LIST</p:link>

        </div>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

The first link make a redirect to main.xhtml passing a id parameter = 1, thus:

```
@Named(value = "workRequestController")
@ViewScoped
public class WorkRequestController implements Serializable {

    public void confirmWorkRequest() throws IOException {
        Integer id = 1;
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "/main.xhtml?id=" + id);
    }
}
```

The second link simply redirect to main page without parameters, The main page is defined in the next way:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="scripts">
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js"></h:outputScript>
    </ui:define>


    <ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{beanController.workOrderId}"/>
            <f:viewAction action="#{beanController.resolveRequestParams}" phase="UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES" />
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="true">
            </p:messages>
            <div class="ui-fluid" jsf:id="itemForm">
                <ui:include src="#{beanController.currentForm}" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>


</ui:composition>
```

If you see for the main page is defined a metadata tag in order to capture the parameter when it is sent through URL. The main page can load either of 2 pages (List.xhtml or View.xhtml) based in the currentForm variable. By default is "List.xhtml", when is sent the parameter id from index.xhtml, the variable currentForm is change to View.xhtml. The bean controller is defined thus:

```
@Named(value = "beanController")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanController implements Serializable {

    private String workOrderId;
    protected String currentForm = "List.xhtml";
    private static List<Model> models;
    private Model model;
    private List<Client> clients;
    private Client client;

    //Initialization model
    static {
        models = new ArrayList<Model>();
        Model model1 = new Model(0, "Model 1", "Description 1");
        Model model2 = new Model(1, "Model 2", "Description 2");
        Model model3 = new Model(2, "Model 3", "Description 3");
        Model model4 = new Model(3, "Model 4", "Description 4");
        Model model5 = new Model(4, "Model 5", "Description 5");
        Model model6 = new Model(5, "Model 6", "Description 6");
        Model model7 = new Model(6, "Model 7", "Description 7");
        Model model8 = new Model(7, "Model 8", "Description 8");

        models.add(model1);
        models.add(model2);
        models.add(model3);
        models.add(model4);
        models.add(model5);
        models.add(model6);
        models.add(model7);
        models.add(model8);
    }

    public void resolveRequestParams() {
        if(workOrderId != null){
            Integer workId = Integer.valueOf(workOrderId);
            model = models.get(workId);
            currentForm = "View.xhtml";
        } else {
            currentForm = "List.xhtml";
        }
    }


    public String getWorkOrderId() {
        return workOrderId;
    }

    public void setWorkOrderId(String workOrderId) {
        this.workOrderId = workOrderId;
    }

    public String getCurrentForm() {
        return currentForm;
    }

    public void setCurrentForm(String currentForm) {
        this.currentForm = currentForm;
    }

    public List<Model> getModels() {
        return models;
    }

    public void setModels(List<Model> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
        Client client1 = new Client(1, "Charles");
        Client client2 = new Client(2, "Michael");
        Client client3 = new Client(3, "Kevin");
        Client client4 = new Client(4, "Jason");
        clients.add(client1);
        clients.add(client2);
        clients.add(client3);
        clients.add(client4);

        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void onSelectClient() {
        model.setClient(client);
    }

    public void prepareView(){

        if(model == null){
            currentForm = "List.xhtml";
        }
        else {

            currentForm = "View.xhtml";

        }

    }

    public void close(){
        model = null;
        currentForm = "List.xhtml";
    }

}
```

The List.xhtml is defined thus:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{beanController.prepareView}"  update=":mainForm:itemForm">View
    </p:commandLink>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p:dataTable var="model" value="#{beanController.models}" selection="#{beanController.model}" rowKey="#{model.id}">

        <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width: 42px"
                  styleClass="align-center"
                  priority="1"/>

        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{model.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{model.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Description">
            <h:outputText value="#{model.description}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

</ui:composition>
```

and the View.xhtml thus:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


    <p:commandLink onclick="PF('ClientList').show();" value="Open Dialog"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{beanController.close}" value="Close" update=":mainForm:itemForm"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p:inputText id="id" value="#{beanController.model.id}" disabled="true"/>
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{beanController.model.name}" disabled="true"/>
    <p:inputText id="description" value="#{beanController.model.description}" disabled="true"/>
    <p:inputText id="client" value="#{beanController.model.client.name}" disabled="true"/>

    <p:dialog id="ClientListDialog"
              modal="true"
              widgetVar="ClientList"
              resizable="false"
              closable="true"
              appendTo="@(body)"
              closeOnEscape="true">
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="ClientTable"
                         class="fit-content-table"
                         binding="#{clients}"
                         value="#{beanController.clients}"
                         var="item"
                         rowKey="#{item.id}"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                         paginatorPosition="top"
                         selection="#{beanController.client}"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         widgetVar="ClientTable">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{beanController.onSelectClient}"
                        onstart="PF('ClientList').hide();"
                        update=":mainForm:client"/>


                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value=""/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{item.name}" filterBy="#{item.id}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{item.name}" filterBy="#{item.name}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

The issue happen when is loaded the View page in the moment that is sent the parameter from index page, in this case is loaded the model in the View page, but when I select the rows for the table displayed in the dialog, the listener beanController.onSelectClient is no being executed for event="rowSelect", while if the View page is loaded from List page without send parameter through the URL the listener works.

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and especially the [mcve] part. Way to much irrelevant code on here for us to wade trough. Also read https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, I created a project just with the minimal to recreate the issue. I think that I can not to minimize more it. What other think can I do?

Comment: Edit the code in the question and replace it with the [mcve]